# Is it possible to validate whether all assets in an entry have been uploaded?

Tags: craft3, craft-pro

Is it possible that all assets are uploaded in a single entry and display success or fail in a friendly way?

Use case: Client uploads 2000 photos at a time in an entry and has to keep scrolling to the bottom of the asset popup box to see if all photos have actually "uploaded" or not.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is an easy way to do this with Craft out of the box. Uploading 2k images to an entry is a bit of an edge case. I would recommend uploading all of those images directly to the asset volume.

That being said, you might want to search the plugin store to see if anyone has created a plugin like this. You could also create your own plugin, copy the code for the asset field, and extend to notify when the upload is complete.

Good luck!